# Azure C# Framework - How to Disable Validation Code to Authenticate

Tags: c#, azure, frameworks, bots, devops

I Set in my azure portal the App Registration for using the AUTH.
I also created a chatbot for that.

my question is how to pass the validation code just skip it.
and get after that like now the RespondsToken.
[image]

Comment: Is this app registered with Azure AD-Multi factor Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is registered with Azure AD MFA,

Rerun the Azure AD Connect wizard and change the user sign-in method from Pass-through Authentication to another method. This change disables Pass-through Authentication on the tenant and uninstalls the Authentication Agent from the server. You must manually uninstall the Authentication Agents from the other servers.

But, If you uninstall a Pass-through Authentication Agent from a server, it causes the server to stop accepting sign-in requests. To avoid breaking the user sign-in capability on your tenant, ensure that you have another Authentication Agent running before you uninstall a Pass-through Authentication Agent.

If your application is registered with azure multi factor authentication, then refer this [removing pass-through authentication q&a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/254401/remove-azure-pass-through-authentication-without-a.html).

In order to bypass authentication like allowing a user single time without performing MFA, then look into this [Microsoft documentation for one-time bypass authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-server-settings).